# Vuex typescript commit type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to convert some vue project using typescript+vue3

Now in my store > `actions.js`

I have a function:

```
const SET_TEST = ({commit}, val: string | number) => {
commit('SET_TEST', val);
```

}

```
export default {
    SET_TEST
}
```

Now, the `{commit}` gives me error saying : `Binding element 'commit' implicitly has an 'any' type` 
my question is, what should be the type of `{commit}` here?

Answer (score 0):

`commit` shouldn't be explicitly typed, the whole function should:

```
const SET_TEST: Action<MyStoreType, MyStateType> = ({commit}, val: string | number) => ...
```